# Getting latest inserted auto-incremented record id using fat-free-framework

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, fat-free-framework

I need to get the id(AUTO-INCREMENTED) of latest inserted record in a table.
I am using fat-free-framework.

I tried to get the latest id by using

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

but it gave me this error

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I am accessing database using fat-free-framework and not using traditional php functions. Can any one guide me how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this code after record inserted

```
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside kumar_v's answer, F3 will automatically populate `$db->_id` after a successfull insert.

Comment: A leading underscore usually indicates something "internal" or potentially "private", which implementation might change in the future. I'd better go with @kumar_v solution, even if it's probably not anything more than a wrapper around `$db->_id`. But since you never know...

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have used the SQL Mapper to create the row in your table, you can just do

```
$object->id;
```

Example (using a table containing quotes):

```
$quote = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'quotes');
if($_POST){
    //overwrite with values just submitted
    $quote->copyFrom('POST');
    $quote->save();
    die("new quote added with id:".$quote->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'quotes');
$quote->get('_id');
```

which '_id' is the id auto increment id field of your table, replace '_id' with yours 
you can read the docs :
https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql-mapper#get